# What is rockstar games phone number

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Need to contact rockstar game services because my vehicle was replaced with another and I can’t get my car back

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to contact Rockstar Games. The phone number is (866) 922-8694, the website offers online support and email.